# If $G$ is a group and $a,\,b\in G$ s.t. $a$ has order $5$ and $a^3b=ba^3$, prove $ab=ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $a,\,b\in G$ such that $a$ has order $5$ and
>   $a^3b=ba^3$. Prove $ab=ba$.

*Attempt.* Since $a^5=e$, multiplying from the left with $a^2$ and from the right with $a^2$ the given equality we get $ba^2=a^2b$. How may we conclude that $ab=ba$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're almost there: $ba^2=a^2b \implies aba^2=a^3b=ba^3 \implies ab=ba$.